# Cannot compile xuggle-xuggler on Centos because of libx264

Tags: linux, configure, xuggler, xuggle

I am trying to compile xuggle-xuggler on my CentOS 6.3 final and am running into some troubles.
The general make in the root directory fails because no makefile is found in libx264.

So I try to go into captive/libx264/csrc and run configure once again. 
Here is the output :

```
[test@localhost:~/Documents/02_Xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/captive/libx264/csrc]$ ./configure 
platform:      X86_64
system:        LINUX
cli:           yes
libx264:       internal
shared:        no
static:        no
asm:           yes
interlaced:    yes
avs:           no
lavf:          no
ffms:          no
gpac:          no
gpl:           yes
thread:        posix
filters:       crop select_every 
debug:         no
gprof:         no
strip:         no
PIC:           no
visualize:     no
bit depth:     8
chroma format: all
You can run 'make' or 'make fprofiled' now.
```

Thing is no makefile is created even though there doesn't seem to be any error :

```
[test@localhost:~/Documents/02_Xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/captive/libx264/csrc]$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Is that normal ? I didn't find anything related to this issue on the web so far, and I struggle to find a solution by myself :s

Any direction would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Julien